# How to skip the login activity in relaunching app after a successful login....?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm a kinda beginner...and i am working on a project that have a login activity and i want to skip the login activity in relaunching... after a successful login.
Pleas define it well if possible!

Comment: post the code you have and we shall help through that

Comment: I'm just starting the project...and i've been googling but still found nothing

Answer (score 0):

use shared preferences set a tag after login lets `loggedin=true` and put a check `onCreate()` if preferences values is true direct it to next activity

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, It's help you.

**LoginActivity.java**

```
    public void onCreate(){

       /*your code in top*/
        SharedPreferences prefs= this.getSharedPreferences("APP", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(press.contains("loggedIn")){
            startActivity(new Intent(this, NextActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
       /*END*/
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Store a variable in Shared Preferences off the app and check it in oncreate of Login Activity if the value is saved move to main activity using intent.

Setting values in Preference:

```
// MY_PREFS_NAME - a static String variable like: 

public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, 
MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("login", "true");
editor.apply();
```

Retrieve data from preference in Oncreate on Login Activity:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString("login", null);
if (restoredText.equals("true")) {
  Intent i=new Intent();
  i.startActivity(this,Activity_you_want_to_show.class);
  finish();
}
```